# mahout classification text input vectorization

Tags: mahout

I am trying to build a classifier with mahout. After the model is built.
I have to "feed" the target documents to the model and get the classification result.

I checked the testcases in the mahout source code, it uses DenseVector which have the fixed amount of fields. 
However, I m using mahout to classify text docs, the input is some string(or array containing strings). How to convert it to a valid "Vector" instance.

I tried the StaticWordEncoder and RandomAccessSparseVector, but the result is not correct. Cannot figure out why. A little bit desperate.

Comment: The "TestClassifierDriver" produce the correct result which proves the model trained should be fine.

Comment: Better go to the mahout user list.

Comment: Solved. I have to convert the document to vecotr instance. The process is a little bit dirty, but it works fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the document into words and populate the vector from those.

I would recommend reading something like [Mahout In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182684) to get more background before attempting this.